# How to Mock SharedFlow for unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-flow

Assume that in one function in viewModel, I get shared flow from `XUseCase`. You can assume as in the following:

```
fun sampleFunction(){
   xUseCase.getFlow()
       .collect {
       // update state
 }
}
```

I am trying to write unit test for this function and checking if the state updated correctly. I am using mockK Library and I have mocked this `XUseCase`.

I am trying to mockK xUseCase.getFlow() response as in the following:

```
val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<FavoriteUpdate>()
sharedFlow.emit(
       (FavoriteUpdate(
           vendorCode = "x2ar",
            isFavorite = true,
            error = null
           ))
        )
every { xUseCase.getFlow() } returns sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()
```

After debugging the unit test, I see thet xUseCase.getFlow() returned empty flow. Is there anything I am missing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
coEvery { xUseCase.getFlow() }.coAnswers {
                flow {
                    emit(
                        'value 1'
                    )
                    emit(
                        'value 2'
                    )
                }
            }
```